# How many possibilities permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let us say, I have the following: **DADA** which we can assign an index to $D_1$ $A_1$ $D_2$ $A_2$.

The possibilities, if the order of every letter in this word counts:

$D_1$ $A_1$ $D_2$ $A_2$

$D_1$ $D_2$ $A_1$ $A_2$

$D_1$ $A_1$ $A_2$ $D_2$

$A_1$ $A_2$ $D_1$ $D_2$

$A_1$ $D_1$ $D_2$ $A_2$

I get **5** possibilities. However, if I take the following formula:

$$\frac{n!}{n_D!\cdot n_A!}$$

plugging in the following information: $n=4$, $n_D=2$ and $n_A=2$, returns a **6**, which shows that there's one more possibility or combination.

Is this correct? Also, how would this be, if the order of every letter didn't count, and instead this forms whole words.

```
EDIT: Every letter with a unique index is treated as a unique single letter.
```

---

*Is this the way the formula should be used?*

[image]

Comment: $A_2D_1A_4D_3$ ?

Comment: @zwim, Yes, seems like I didn't know about this one. Thanks. What about the `when the order of every letter does not count, and does count`?

Comment: @zwim, please se my edit.

Comment: To be clear, with your subscripts on your letters you have still only ever listed those subscripts in increasing order.  You only ever wrote $D_1D_2A_1A_2$.  What about $D_1D_2A_2A_1$ or $D_2D_1A_1A_2$ or $D_2D_1A_2A_1$?  I suspect this is what you are missing

Comment: The number of unique arrangements if we ignore subscripts is of course the same as the number of unique arrangements if we require the subscripts go in increasing order for each letter.  This is not the same as the number of unique arrangements if we allow subscripts to be in any order.

Comment: @JMoravitz, what does this really mean? How does the order impact this? Do you have a real answer here?

Comment: "*what does this really mean?*"  That $D_1D_2A_1A_2$ is different than $D_2D_1A_1A_2$ *if you want it to be different*... and that both are possible arrangements *if you want them to both be possible arrangements*

Comment: Yes, based on their index number subscript. Any real long answer?

Comment: ... any real long answer to what?  I haven't heard a well formulated question yet.  How many ways can you arrange these letters assuming every letter is unique because the letters themselves are different?  $n!$.  How many ways can you arrange these letters if some letters are the same but they all have different subscripts?  Still $n!$... that should have been obvious.  How many ways if some letters are the same and we don't have subscripts making them unique?  Now this is when we have that $\frac{n!}{p!q!\cdots}$

Comment: I strongly recommend for the moment ignoring the existence of factorials and formulas and really stop and understand how to find and calculate the answers *from first principles*.  Understand where those formulas you seem so gung ho about using come from in the first place.  Just knowing the end result of a formula and trying to remember when it is used is not beneficial to the learning process.  Actually *understanding* the formulas and why they are what they are is far better.

Comment: @JMoravitz, what is the difference between, `If the order of every letter in your word counts (see every letter as a unique letter)` and `If the order of the same letters don’t count, write down all different words you can make (the words don’t have to mean anything)`?

Comment: What is the difference between those questions?  Again... in the first question you have $D_1D_2A_1A_2$ is "*different*" than $D_2D_1A_1A_2$.  In the second question those are considered "*the same*"

Comment: And I will emphasize again, learn this stuff *from first principles*.  There is **no** reason why you should have written $P(\color{red}{4},\color{blue}{4})$ ever.  Just think of it as $4!$ or even better yet think of it as $4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$.

Comment: Aha. So, in the second question, D, D, and A, A are considered the same, regardless of the subscript index. Then, it means, that `24 / 4 = 6` so gives less combinations?

Comment: Dude, I am doing 4 * 3 * 2 * 1, that's how I learned this.

Comment: But, I have an issue understnading what should be done with the stuff below, in this context, it shows 4-4, is that really correct? when the formula states multiplication?

Comment: Why are you talking about $4-4$?  Again... ignore the existence of these $P$ formulas and $C$ formulas and such and think from first principles until you are more comfortable.  Why does subtraction occur in the formula for $P(n,r)$?  To simplify things.  It is far easier and more natural to think of $P(n,r)$ as $\underbrace{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots (n-r+1)}_{r~\text{terms in product}}$.  Do some people prefer to write this as $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$?  Yes.  Do you need to think of it that way right now?  Absolutely not.  Will it eventually be useful to think of it that way?  Sometimes, yes.

Comment: @JMoravitz, So,**24** when the order does count, and **6** when the order does not count? **Right?**

Comment: The order in which D's and A's occur is important for both.  DDAA is different than DADA in just the same way that $D_1D_2A_1A_2$ is different than $D_1A_1D_2A_2$.  I would not call the scenario of counting DDAA,DADA,DAAD etc as being that "order does not count."  It very much does.  The distinction is that in counting DDAA,DADA, DAAD etc we have that if you swap two of the D's positions, for example swapping the two D's in DDAA, you get back an identical arrangement.  DDAA looks exactly like DDAA even though we swapped the two D's around.  Unlike in $D_1D_2A_1A_2$ if we swap the D's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given word is **DADA**, it is a four letter word, but two letters, D and A, are repeated twice.

Let's, initially for no reason (don't worry about that), assign indices to all four letters. In this way: D<sub>1</sub>A<sub>1</sub>D<sub>2</sub>A<sub>2</sub>.

#### CASE-1

Let's consider D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> are not the same letter (element), similarly D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>1</sub> are not same letters, they all are different from each other.
i.e., D<sub>1</sub> ≠ D<sub>2</sub> and A<sub>1</sub> ≠ A<sub>2</sub>.

Now, let's list all the ways in which we can arrange these letters -

1. A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
2. A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub>
3. A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
4. A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub>

--

5. A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
6. A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
7. A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub>
8. A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub>

--

9. D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
10. D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub>
11. D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub>
12. D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub>

--

13. D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
14. D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
15. D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub>
16. D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>1</sub>

--

17. D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
18. D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
19. D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub>
20. D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub> A<sub>1</sub>

--

21. A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
22. A<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>2</sub>
23. A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> D<sub>2</sub> A<sub>1</sub>
24. A<sub>2</sub> D<sub>2</sub> D<sub>1</sub> A<sub>1</sub>

You can see that, by considering D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> as different letters and A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> as different letters, we get a total of 24 different ways of arrangements.

---

#### CASE-2

Now, let's consider D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> as the same letters and A<sub>1</sub> and A<sub>2</sub> also as the same letters (you can erase the indices), i.e., D<sub>1</sub> = D<sub>2</sub> = D, and A<sub>1</sub> = A<sub>2</sub> = A.

So, let's again list those 24 permutations, **but now, erasing those indices**:

1. A A D D
2. A A D D
3. A A D D
4. A A D D

--

5. A D A D
6. A D A D
7. A D A D
8. A D A D

--

9. D A A D
10. D A A D
11. D A A D
12. D A A D

--

13. D A D A
14. D A D A
15. D A D A
16. D A D A

--

17. D D A A
18. D D A A
19. D D A A
20. D D A A

--

21. A D D A
22. A D D A
23. A D D A
24. A D D A

You can see that by erasing those indices, you're list same type of arrangement 4 times.

So, if you **not consider repeated letters as different letters**, then number of different permutations are 24/4 = 6 (since there are 4 types of same arrangement).

##### Edit 1{

The formula that you were using: n!/n<sub>D</sub>!⋅n<sub>A</sub>!, is applicable here, where n<sub>D</sub> = 2 (number of D's) and n<sub>A</sub> = 2 (number of A's). So n<sub>D</sub>!⋅n<sub>A</sub>! = 2!.2! = 4, which is exactly exactly equal to what we are dividing from n!, i.e., 24/4 = 6.

##### }

So, let's list them again by ignoring repeated arrangements-

1. A A D D
2. A D A D
3. D A A D
4. D A D A
5. D D A A
6. A D D A

So, hence 6 permutations, if you **not consider repeated letters as different letters**.

---

Please consider reading my both answers for maximum details.

Comment: You are the **BEST!**

Comment: I Added Edit 1{...} to detail about a formula...

Answer (score 2):

> The possibilities, if the order of every letter in this word counts

As you have said, if the order of every letter matters, then you are supposed so treat each letter as a completely different letter (i.e., D<sub>1</sub> is different from D<sub>3</sub>).

So, So, Number of ways you can arrange 4 completely different elements, keeping each at one of the four given places, without repetition of any element, is given by <sup>n</sup>P<sub>r</sub> = `n!/(n-r)!`

**So, 4!/(4-4)! = 4!/0! = 4! = 24 ways, i.e, you can arrange them in 24 different ways.**

---

If you want to consider both D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>3</sub> as same, then the number of ways you can arrange those letters is given by <sup>n</sup>P<sub>r</sub>/n<sub>D</sub> = n!/(n-r)!•n<sub>D</sub>.

Similarly, if you **also** want to consider A<sub>2</sub> and A<sub>4</sub> as same letters, then number of ways you can arrange those letters is given by <sup>n</sup>P<sub>r</sub>/n<sub>D</sub>•n<sub>A</sub> = n!/(n-r)!•n<sub>D</sub>•n<sub>A</sub>.

---

**The problem with your answer** is that you're are considering all the repeating letters as different and trying to find their permutations, but in calculation, you're using the formula used to find the number of possibilities when **repeating letters are NOT treated as different letters**

Comment: Please see my edits, and look closely at the letters.

Comment: $D_1$ $A_1$ $D_2$ $A_2$

Comment: I get **24/4=6**

Comment: @AlbinM since you're treat each repeated letters as a different letter, so you should not divide nPr value with Na!.Nd! value.

Comment: ByteManager, please show me the steps for calculating this? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, sure, but I need some time, I'm typing on phone.. :)

Comment: Nice boss! ;-) You are greatest!

Comment: Can you say again what's your doubt? I'm bit confused what to emphasize in my answer?

Comment: Yes, why is it **24** and not **6**. Also, what about: `If the order of every letter in your word counts (see every letter as a unique letter)` and `If the order of the same letters don’t count, write down all different words you can make (the words don’t have to mean anything)`? How does it differ and what would be the output depending on this?

Comment: "*Why is it 24*"  Because 24 counts the list $D_1D_2A_1A_2,~D_2D_1A_1A_2,~D_1D_2A_2A_1,~D_2D_1A_2A_1,D_1A_1D_2A_2,D_1A_2D_2A_1,\dots$.  Meanwhile $6$ counts the list $DDAA,~DADA,~DAAD,\dots$

Comment: WHAT **LIST** ?

Comment: The list of possible arrangements of the letters... in the first case where the letters are given unique identifying subscripts that make two arrangements different so long as the subscripts or letters are different... and in the second case where such subscripts don't exist

Comment: So, **24** when the order does count, and **6** when the order does not count? **Right?**

Comment: So,**24** when the order does count, and **6** when the order does not count? **Right?**